# Cross compile a shared Library under Linux for windows

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I want to get a windows-DLL, but I want to compile it under Ubuntu-Linux.

Building an Executable was simple: `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build wrapper.go` generates a `wrapper.exe`, that behaves as expected.

but building a DLL with `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -buildmode=c-shared wrapper.go` results in error:

```
running gcc failed: exit status 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mconsole’; did you mean ‘--compile’?
```

I would prefer not to install and run `go` under windows, because my complete tool chain is running under Ubuntu

`go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64`

Comment: This seems very compiler implementation specific,so what's your `go version` and `go env`?

Comment: Also what gcc libraries did you install for compiling to windows?

Comment: I'm currently not using it to build c-shared libraries (and it could use a Go version update), but I did successfully build c-shared libraries with it in the past: https://github.com/tehsphinx/golang_cgo_windows/blob/master/Dockerfile. If you want to quickly test it, its also on docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/tehsphinx/golang_cgo_windows/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: what makes me wonder is, that building a `.exe` is working, but not building a `.dll`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would pass `-x` to the call to `go build -buildmode=c-shared ...`, you'd notice that in that mode the linker from the Go toolchain calls out to the external C linker; for instance, here on GNU/Linux with Go 1.15.x, I have:

`mkdir -p $WORK/b001/exe/`
`cd $WORK/b001/exe/`
`/home/username/devel/golang-1.15.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link -o cshared.dll -importcfg $WORK/b001/importcfg.link -buildmode=c-shared -buildid=OJVN3iT0GI_DEAMVbLDu/o9eT_YGfUiRe07beNQAA/-xRRfDcM8nVc03rltdqz/OJVN3iT0GI_DEAMVbLDu -extld=gcc $WORK/b001/_pkg_.a`
`# command-line-arguments`
`loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo`
`/home/username/devel/golang-1.15.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1`
`gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mconsole’; did you mean ‘--compile’?`

Note that `pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link` is called with `-extld=gcc`, and from [`go doc cmd/link`](https://golang.org/cmd/link), we gather that

> -extld linker
> Set the external linker (default "clang" or "gcc").

My guess is that in order to produce a C-compatible dynamic library, the Go toolchain relies on an external C linker, and that is carried out by [`cgo` machinery](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo) — at which there's actually a hint in the [documentation of `-buildmode=c-shared`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_modes):

> -buildmode=c-shared
> Build the listed main package, plus all packages it imports,
> into a C shared library. The only callable symbols will
> be those functions exported using a `cgo` `//export` comment.
> Requires exactly one main package to be listed.

Hence my guess is that in order to do what you want you have to:

- Install a cross-compiler supporting Windows/i386 — you can start with [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32).
- Set up the environment before calling `go build` as explained in the [`cgo` docs](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo) so that the Go toolchain calls the Windows-specific linker.
- Verify it works by running `go build` with the `-x` command-line option.